# button element not working for empty_cart

Tags: expresso-store

Having some trouble getting the empty_cart form element to work as a `<button>` element.

For example this works:

```
{exp:store:checkout next="store/checkout/1"}
  ...
  <input type="submit" name="empty_cart" value="Empty Cart" />
{/exp:store}
```

However using a button element instead of an input will not:

```
{exp:store:checkout next="store/checkout/1"}
  ...
  <button type="submit" name="empty_cart">Empty Cart</button>
{/exp:store:checkout}
```

The other inputs such as "update_cart" work fine as button elements. Is this a bug or am I just missing something?

The reason I want to use button elements is for styling purposes and I have to add an icon in the button using the CSS framework the project uses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is submitted data. A button (of submit type) will submit a form, but it won't pass any value as POST and Store requires that to confirm what you want to do.

Try:

```
<button type="submit" name="empty_cart" value="Empty Cart">Empty Cart</button>
```

Now it has a value, it'll be submitted with the form data and Store can read it.

Comment: Missed that one. Thanks. Works as expected now.